# What the am I doing wrong here? array decides not to keep its values

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

Just read some puding strings from set of puding files and putting them to a puding array to be sorted later by the puding qsort_r. How hard can it be?

```
printf("%d -- %s\n", arr_i, words[arr_i]);
```

so it prints accurately.

but this

```
        printf("%d : %s\n", i, words[i]);
```

only shows the words[0] repeatedly.

before i break my new laptop out of anger and frustration can someone help me to find the problem?

any help is appreciated!

thank you.

```
static void *reducer(void *arg){
    int index=*((int*)arg);
    printf("reducer %d here! %d\n", index, max_words_per_input_file[index]);

    // we will put words of N files here.
    char* words[max_words_per_input_file[index]];

    int j;
    int i;
    int arr_i=0;
    char file_name[FILE_NAME_SIZE];

    // read file
    char * temp;
    FILE *file;
    for(j=0; j<R; j++){
        // create file name
        // tempj-i 0<=j<=N-1 0<=i<=R-1
        char file_name[FILE_NAME_SIZE];
        sprintf(file_name, "temp%d-%d", j, index);

        file = fopen(file_name, "r");
        if (file == NULL) {
            printf("Error opening file\n");
            return NULL;
        }

        // scan the next %s from stream and put it to temp
        while(fscanf(file, "%s", &(*temp)) > 0){ 
            printf("reducer reads: %s\n", temp);

            words[arr_i] = temp; 
            printf("%d -- %s\n", arr_i, words[arr_i]);

            arr_i++;

        }
        fclose(file);
    }


    // open a temp file to write 
    FILE *temp_output_file;
    sprintf(file_name, "temp%d", index);
    temp_output_file = fopen(file_name, "w");
    if (temp_output_file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return NULL;
    }   
    // fprintf(temp_output_file, "%s\n", temp);

    fclose(temp_output_file);

    for(i=0; i<arr_i; i++){
        printf("%d : %s\n", i, words[i]);       
    }

    int thunk = WORD_LENGTH; 
    qsort_r(words, sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]), sizeof(words[0]), cmpstringp, &thunk);

    //hash 


    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Who does up-vote and star this question? Is this a team-work and you push the question? Because there is a lot you could and should improve IMHO. See [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should be able to debug this yourself, but I like the line that you might break your laptop out of anger reminds me when I started coding :D

Comment: @Theolodis: Some people (ab-)use "favorite" as a bookmark for low-quality questions to later look at it again after it's been improved. (Not necessarily the case here, just saying.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually have *two* problems.

The first is that `words` is an array of pointers, and you make all pointers the same, they all point to the same location.

The second problem is much worse, and it's that you don't initialize `temp` which means its value will be *indeterminate* and point to a seemingly random location which you then write to. This leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What you should do is to allocate memory for `temp`, one new allocation for each string you read. And don't forget to free the memory once you're done with it.